# Convert a single valued dictionary to multivalued dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary

```
total_values = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

Now I want to convert this dictionary into multivalued one.
like

```
total_values = {'a':(1,False), 'b':(2, True), 'c':(3, True)}
```

Please tell me the most pythonic way to do that....

How the True and False values are determined doesn't matter, suppose it as a value of a boolean variable which I can use for this..

Comment: We need more detail; what determines the boolean values?

Comment: boolean values doesn;t matter here..watever it can be..just need to know the way of conversion.,,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May as well make it random:

```
from random import choice
for key in total_values:
    total_values[key] = (total_values[key], choice((True, False)))
```

Answer (score 6):

In 2.6:

```
dict( (k, (v, <boolean expression>)) for (k, v) in total_values.iteritems() )
```

In 2.7:

```
{ k:(v, <boolean expression>) for (k, v) in total_values.iteritems() }
```

In 3.0, (thanks @C2H5OH):

```
{ k:(v, <boolean expression>) for (k, v) in total_values.items() }
```

Note that these solutions create a brand new dictionary. If you want to modify the existing dictionary, @MartijnPieters's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11491451/9990) is in the right direction.

Comment: Python 3 syntax is the same as 2.7 as far as dictionary expressions are concerned.

Comment: In Python 3.0 is like in 2.7 but you need to change `.iteritems()` with `.items()`.  And also, the parenthesis around `(k, v)` after the `for` keyword are optional in all versions.

Comment: @C2H5OH: Thanks for the clarification. The parentheses are a personal choice; since it is impracticable to always omit them, I find it easier and more readable to always use them.